# Qt events getting stuck running in an Eclipse RCP app Java plugin on Windows 10 64-bit?

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, qt, java-native-interface

Ok, so I have a Qt 4.8.7 gui running in an Eclipse RCP app from a Java plugin. I have a QMainWindow parented by a org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite and displayed in an org.eclipse.ui.part.EditorPart. I use the IStartup interface to allocate the QApplication object on Eclipse app startup via a JNI call in the Java gui thread, i.e. Display.getDefault().syncExec(new Runnable() {... Interestingly, calling exec() on the QApplication object is not required as the Qt event queue appears to be happily processing along after QApplication is allocated.

Amazingly, this works without issue on Windows 7/8 64-bit. However, when I take the exact same build and run it on Windows 10 64-bit, Qt events seem to get stuck. For example, say I have a column of unchecked QCheckBox widgets in my QMainWindow (inside a Composite, inside an EditorPart, inside an Eclipse RCP app) and I start checking them, nothing appears to happen, but when I click outside the Eclipse RCP app entirely, like on the taskbar, all the QCheckBox's that I checked will then draw checked.

Weird, huh? Any ideas on what changed between Windows 7/8 and 10?

Let me reiterate. This works flawlessly on Windows 7/8 64-bit. The issue is under Windows 10 64-bit. Unfortunately, I'm unable to share code. Also, I realize what I've done here is a bit insane, but it is what it is because legacy.

Thanks!

**Update:**

I think I have narrowed it down to a problem with the QEvent::UpdateRequest event. Here is a printout of normal operations following the event around:

```
52686 painting\qbackingstore.cpp 537 sendUpdateRequest QEvent::UpdateRequest 
52687 kernel\qapplication.cpp 3897 QApplication::notify QEvent::UpdateRequest 
52688 kernel\qwidget.cpp 8693 QWidget::event QEvent::UpdateRequest 
52689 kernel\qapplication.cpp 3897 QApplication::notify QEvent::UpdateRequest
```

But when things get stuck, the printout simply stops after the sendUpdateRequest() call, i.e.

```
52974 painting\qbackingstore.cpp 537 sendUpdateRequest QEvent::UpdateRequest
```

Mouse hover/tracking/clicking events are still going through, but it's like this event is stuck. And I say "stuck" specifically because, as I said before, when I click *outside* the app, the event seems to unstick and the expected behaviour then happens, i.e.

```
52975 kernel\qapplication.cpp 3897 QApplication::notify QEvent::UpdateRequest 
52976 kernel\qwidget.cpp 8693 QWidget::event QEvent::UpdateRequest 
52977 kernel\qapplication.cpp 3897 QApplication::notify QEvent::UpdateRequest
```

**Update 2:**

I should add that the QtWinMigrate widget (from [Qt/MFC Migration Framework](https://github.com/qtproject/qt-solutions/tree/master/qtwinmigrate)) is used to facilitate embedding into the org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.

**Update 3:**

It is 100% reproducible when I launch a modal QDialog. Is there something about a QDialog that would be helpful? Doesn't a QDialog have it's own little event loop? Does that tell me anything?

**Update 4:**

I managed to get a Visual Studio remote debugging session going which allowed the app the keep focus when I hit my conditional breakpoint of "event->t == QEvent::UpdateRequest" at qcoreapplication.cpp(1405): QCoreApplication::postEvent(). From there, the WIN32 API method PostMessage(d->internalHwnd, WM_QT_SENDPOSTEDEVENTS, 0, 0) is called. From there, I was then able to figure out that execution gets stuck in the "while" loop in qeventdispatcher_win.cpp(721): QEventDispatcherWin32::processEvents(). I think it gets stuck because of the "continue" at line 801, i.e.

```
if (d->internalHwnd == msg.hwnd && msg.message == WM_QT_SENDPOSTEDEVENTS) {
    if (seenWM_QT_SENDPOSTEDEVENTS) {
        // when calling processEvents() "manually", we only want to send posted
        // events once
        needWM_QT_SENDPOSTEDEVENTS = true;
        continue;
    }
    seenWM_QT_SENDPOSTEDEVENTS = true;
}
```

I don't know why this is happening. I don't know why the behaviour is different in a QDialog vs a QMainWindow. All I can say is that I commented out that "continue" and the issue goes away. Can anyone even begin to explain this to me?

**Update 5:**

The difference between Win7 and Win10 is that on Win7, at qeventdispatcher_win.cpp(784),

```
waitRet = MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx(nCount, pHandles, 0, QS_ALLINPUT, MWMO_ALERTABLE);
```

times out, the loop is broken, and processEvents can finish. On Win10, MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx() never times out. There are messages constantly coming in, most of them are WM_QT_SENDPOSTEDEVENTS.

Can anyone explain this please?

Comment: Could you show a [mcve]?

Comment: Sorry. Not at this time. I was simply hoping to get a, "Hey, that happened to me, too! <blank> fixed it!" I accept that that may not be very likely. I mean, judging from the small number of posts, embedding Qt into Eclipse apps isn't exactly commonplace.

Comment: Well, somebody's high on their horse. Just because a question doesn't have an MCV example doesn't make it an invalid question.

Comment: As it turns out, I can't provide a MCV example even if I wanted. The QMainWindow giving me the problem is very complex. I attempted to simplify the problem, but I can't reproduce it. There's something about this specific window (which I most certainly can't share) that is giving me grief. If you would kindly, un-downvote my question, that would be most appreciated.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Hey, if it was you who downvoted my question can you please undo that? I need visibility here and for whatever reason you've attempted to bury my question.

Comment: That is not my downvote.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. The bowels of Qt are not fun...